# How to dissect uneven space in log with filebeat processors

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, filebeat

I have a python microservice that output logs like so:

```
INFO    ; 2022-12-02 01:30:00; bla bla bla...
DEBUG   ; 2022-12-02 01:30:00; bla bla bla...
```

Note how the space is different on the loglevel.
I am parsing it like so:

```
                    - dissect:
                        tokenizer: "%{log.level}    ;%{+timestamp} ; %{?message}"
                        field: "message"
                        target_prefix: ""
```

Which work for the first line, not the second.
Anyone know if there is a solution for such case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [right-padding modifier](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dissect-processor.html#dissect-modifier-skip-right-padding)

```
                         add this
                           || 
- dissect:                 vv
    tokenizer: "%{log.level->};%{+timestamp} ; %{?message}"
    field: "message"
    target_prefix: ""
```